# MonoDevelop HTML Tag Matching Error

Tags: asp.net, html, mono, ubuntu-11.10

I'm experiencing something really strange in MonoDevelop.  When writing standard HTML, I'm getting weird Parser warnings telling me that my tags don't match.

In the image below, the blue squiggly is telling me that "Tag div is implicityly closed by tag "div".  The red squiggly is telling me that the closing /div tag has no opening tag.

[image]

As far as I can tell, my html is valid.  Can anybody suggest anything as to why I'm seeing this error?

Thanks in advance!

### **UPDATE**

[The bug has been fixed!](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3588)  Thanks, Mono Team!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in MonoDevelop. Could you file it at bugzilla.xamarin.com?

Comment: Based on your profile information, I'm going to assume that there is a no more professional or authoritative opinion than yours and that this is indeed a bug :)  Thank you!